# MATLAB - Finite element on nonuniform grid

Tags: matlab

I'm solving a second order differential equation in MATLAB using a finite element method, where I write the second order derivative of a function f  as:

d^2f/dx^2 = (f_{i}-f_{i-1}/(x_{i}-x{i-1}) - f_{i+1}-f_{i}/(x_{i+1}-x{i})/(x_{i+1}-x{i-1})/2

Now this operation on f can be translated into a matrix, for which I can then find the eigenvectors, which then are the solutions to the given differential equation.
All this works well for a uniform grid of x-values, i.e. same spacing. But when I try to do it for a nonuniform I get oscillations that should not be there, because the values in the matrix are weighted differently depending on how close the neighbouring grid points are.
Is my approach wrong? Should I use some kind of weighting to take care of the nonuniformity?

Comment: Would interpolating your data into an uniform grid solve your problem?

Comment: Yes but unfortunately it is necessary that I use a nonuniform grid, because of limited computational power.

Comment: I know you are probably no longer looking at this issue, but is there a pastebin or something similar where you can give a minimal example of the problematic code?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I got it right, but the relation you wrote:
d^2f/dx^2 = (f_{i}-f_{i-1}/(x_{i}-x{i-1}) - f_{i+1}-f_{i}/(x_{i+1}-x{i})/(x_{i+1}-x{i-1})/2

looks like finite difference NOT finite element!!!

Otherwise, finite element method does not care (much) about the change of element size from one point to the other in most of the mechanics problems.

If you are handling a finite difference problem, the method does not have to have a regular mesh, but the relations have to be written "carefully" in order to avoid the confusion that may be included in the system matrices.